# Android TV emulator not recognizing media key events

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I have this event handler in my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
            //do something
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:
            //do something
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

While debugging in Android TV device emulator, I can see KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT and KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE when I press a button in directional pad extended control.

But when I press "fast forward" or "rewind" media keys, the key up event is triggered, but the key code is "unrecognized".

> KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_UNKNOWN, scanCode=208...

Is this a Google bug or am I doing something wrong here?

[image: Directional pad extended control in Android TV emulator]

Comment: Just a wild shot in the dark here, but have you tried checking the keyCode that is supplied to onKeyUp with `KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode)`? You could also try and override `dispatchKeyEvent` and see if the KeyEvent is messed up there as well.

Comment: keyCode returned is KEYCODE_UNKNOWN. "ScanCode" is 208

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Even in FireStick I get KEYCODE_UNKNOWN

Comment: No, sorry, never did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the TV Emulator actually does not provide the correct keycode here, which seems to be a bug.

You can simulate this via the command line:

`adb shell input dpad keyevent 90`

This will trigger the `KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD` button.